# implementing word2vec with negative sampling

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, neural-network, word2vec, word-embedding

I am trying to implement forward and back propagation for word2vec using skip-gram. I am new to neural networks, but from my understanding, this is how it goes:

1. take a dot product of the input vectors and matrix of randomly initialized weights
2. Activate (sigmoid or softmax?)
3. take a dot product of the activated hidden layer and another matrix of randomly initialized weights
4. Activate (sigmoid or softmax?)
5. We somehow compare the output that we get after step 4, and calculate the derivative of error (target-output) with respect to each weight in the matrix. We subtract the derivative from the current weight. We do this for both the output-hidden layers, and hidden-input layers. We do this many times until we are good enough.

Please correct me if anything went wrong above.

So now my questions are:

1. What should be the target for both correct skip-grams, and negative samples? Are they 1 and 0, respectively? Or should it be the skip-gram's context? I am really not sure.
2. How should the loss be calculated?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether its the answer of your questions or not but its for completing your question (I am sure!). I don't think in the second step we use sigmoid or softmax function because the first dot project is only for extraction of target word's vector from matrix W (first matrix).
please look at these:

http://mccormickml.com/2016/04/19/word2vec-tutorial-the-skip-gram-model/

section 16.2 of this chapter of this book, it was so so so helpful for me
https://web.stanford.edu/~jurafsky/slp3/16.pdf